# Unable to resolve internet addresses on ADSL modem used as a Wireless AP

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, wireless-access-point

I set up my ADSL modem (TP-Link TD-W8901N) to function as a wireless AP [[Reference](https://www.tp-link.com/in/support/faq/417/)] as follows:

1. I unplugged the cable going into the RJ-11 port.
2. I connected the cable leaving my Optical Network Terminal (ONT) to LAN1.

[image: Network setup]

The modem is set to have a static IP of `192.168.1.1`, which is in the same subnet as the ONT (which has an IP of `192.168.1.251`). I have disabled DHCP, and there is obviously no NAT.

The ONT is configured to connect to my ISP using PPPoE, and is assigned a dynamic public IP. The private IP is `192.168.1.251`, and it has a DHCP server running.

When I connect to the modem over WLAN, I am able to ping and access the web interface of the ONT (`192.168.1.251`). However, I am unable to ping any public IPs like `8.8.8.8` or browse the web.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post a diagram of your network, with relevant IP addresses for the necessary devices?

Comment: I've added a network diagram!

Comment: Why does your AP (ADSL modem) use the same IP address as the ONT (which, as you say, has the private IP `192.168.1.1` in addition to 192.168.1.251)?

Comment: @grawity Sorry, that was a typo! I've fixed it.

Comment: Have you connected the "ADSL Router" using the WAN port, or one of the LAN ports? If you've used the WAN port then you may have NAT being provided by the ADSL router. You would need to make sure you've also configured correct default gateway addresses for your ADSL router and your workstation.

Comment: It's one of the LAN ports. The router's only "WAN port" is an RJ11. To be honest, I'm not sure how NAT is supposed to happen on a network like this, but there seem to be a number of tutorials and guides (take a look at the linked one) that suggest that the router does not have to be explicitly configured to send packets addressed to the public internet to the ONT. I don't understand IP well enough, but I'm confused as to how the packet would even reach the ONT without the proper routing information.

Comment: Answer: Default gateway. Your ONT has an internal IP (192.168.1.251 - subnet 255.255.255.0). You would configure your ADSL router to have an IP (e.g. 192.168.1.1, subnet 255.255.255.0, Default gateway 192.168.1.251). You would configure your workstation to have an IP, say, 192.168.1.2, subnet 255.255.255.0, default gateway 192.168.1.251. Your ADSL router is not doing any routing because it is acting as an AP (the fact you've plugged the router into the LAN port and then to the ONT. This seetup should work. However, what device is this "ONT"? Is it a router, or just a modem?

Comment: Ack, of course! How stupid of me. The workstation was set to a static IP with 192.168.1.1 set as the gateway. I changed it to DHCP and the DHCP server on the ONT responded, which fixed the problem! "ONT" = "Optical Network Terminal", I guess it's the optical equivalent of a DSL modem + router. The ONT in my case, uses PPPoE to connect to the ISP over fiber and performs NAT at the edge of my home network.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the workstation's gateway was set to the ADSL router, `192.168.1.1`. Setting the workstation to use DHCP resolved all issues. Alternatively, you could also manually set up the IP configuration with the gateway set to the ONT, `192.168.1.251`.

Additionally, to ensure that there are no IP conflicts, I moved the ADSL router's IP (`192.168.1.1`) outside the DHCP range of the ONT.